# "Could not complete execution for Gradle Test Executor 2" error appears after gradle execution on bitbucket pipelines

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, testng, bitbucket-pipelines

Tools used:

```
Java 8
Gradle 4.0
Selenium
Selenium Grid
TestNG
Docker
Bitbucket
Bitbucket pipelines
```

When I'm executing my tests via bitbucket pipelines I've got these errors:

1. "Could not complete execution for Gradle Test Executor 2" error (not whole suite executed. Total tests count: 29, executed 9, failed 2. One assertion error and another one is "Could not complete execution for Gradle Test Executor 2"; [image]
2. If I did an execution again sometimes I have this error: "Failed Container 'docker' exceeded memory limit."[image]

Everything works fine when I'm running the tests locally. Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `--debug` to your Gradle command and see if there are exceptions that are causing these failures.

I faced a similar problem because Gradle could not find the test listener class. After fixing that, the tests were easily able to run.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by downgrading the TestNG dependency in build.gradle file from 7.0.1 to 6.14.3

Comment: not working for me :(

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to change `build.gradle` file

for me, at the beginning it was:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and it was not working properly

So I needed to change to:

```
test {
    useTestNG()
}
```

after that, all the tests are starting as expected.